# ZEND Guard changes filename capitalization

Tags: zend-guard

I use Zend Guard 5.0.1 and I've just noticed that it changes the capitalization of files that it is excluding (Copy as is). Since my filenames are case-sensitive this must have just changed as nothing works now, but I don't know how.
I use Obfuscation for Variables and Functions (not Classes).
I have tried to delete and create the project from scratch as there are other projects which don't just capitalization.
Does anyone have any clues?
Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Try to use command-line tools (zendenc52/zendenc53) from your Zend Guard. They do not mess filename capitalization.